# discover Services on a Bluetooth LE not working on Nexus7 tablet

Tags: android, bluetooth, gatt

I have run the application in our Nexus 7 tablet. The application listed the device on the  screen and connected to the BLE device.
On data reading part got some issue.

One the application  connected  successfully, we need to discover all the service on the devices. The discoverServices() function not working in our application. Getting some exception  (android.os.DeadObjectException). Getting issue in following part

public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                int newState) {

```
        // String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {


            Log.i("zzz", "Attempting to start service discovery:"
                    + gatt.discoverServices());



        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {

            Log.i("zzzzz", "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            // broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception. This way I can compare it to my dead object exceptions i get when trying to use gatt with Bluetooth turned off.

Comment: We are getting the following exception                                                              android.os.DeadObjectException
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
 at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.discoverServices(IBluetoothGatt.java:787)
 at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.discoverServices(BluetoothGatt.java:753)
 at com.example.ble.Activity2$1.onConnectionStateChange(Activity2.java:106)
 at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:168)
 at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothG

Comment: Analyse your log further for Bluetooth errors. I got the DeadObjectException on any Bluetooth regarding method call after Bluetooth suddenly was turned off (e.g. by my app) or Turning off of Bluetooth failed.
`E/BluetoothAdapterState(3474): Error disabling Bluetooth
 D/BluetoothAdapterProperties(3474): Setting state to 10
I/BluetoothAdapterState(3474): Bluetooth adapter state changed: 13-> 10
D/BluetoothAdapterService(3474): Broadcasting updateAdapterState() to 1 receivers.
E/BluetoothAdapterState(3474): Killing the process to force a restart as part cleanup ..
DeadOjectExceptions coming next`

Comment: Are you calling the posted code in the Bluetooth Adapter state changed event?

Comment: Excuse me , do you solve this problem ? I have the same error log...`E/BluetoothGatt( 3667): android.os.DeadObjectException`

Comment: May be it is our device issue, we installed new OS version and works, thank you.